# Mup : could use multi mongo version same hosting?

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, docker-compose

I'm base on `meteor version(2.0)` and `mup version(1.5.3)`.

I want to use mup deploy to server and use multi mongo version.

Ex :

- IP: 1.2.3.4:3000 for app1 , use mongo 4.0.10
- IP: 1.2.3.4:5000 for app2 , use mongo 4.2.8

How can I do ?

Comment: You need to not use the default bridge network. This is a legacy network and doesn't support many features that are available on user-defined networks.

Comment: @larsks thank you. If I want to use alias network , how can I do ?

Comment: ignore alias for a minute ... are you able to launch a mongo container using docker-compose ?   start simple and get something running

Comment: @ScottStensland start mongo container with docker compose, it done without alias.

Comment: please update your question and explain the problem you think gets solved by using a network alias perhaps people can suggest a solution

Comment: @ScottStensland updated my question.

Comment: to keep it simple only use one mongo version per machine and just put other mongo version on its own box

Comment: @ScottStensland , mup not support multi mongo version on the same hosting. thank for your reply.